# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProduct>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>

Tags: c#, generics

My application uses

```
var results= websiteDetail.Detail.GetProductDetails<MyProduct>(code, websiteDetail.Detail.NegativeWords);
```

which in turn now calls

```
public List<T> GetProductDetails<T>(string websiteHtmlCode, List<string> negativeWords)
{
    List<T> result = new List<T>();
    foreach (var item in GetProducts(negativeWords))
    {
        result.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T)));
    }
    return result;
}

private List<MyProduct> GetProducts(List<string> negativeWords)
{
     // logic
}
```

However, if I update the code to:

```
public List<T> GetProductDetails<T>(string websiteHtmlCode, List<string> negativeWords)
{
    return GetProducts(negativeWords); //ERROR
}
```

I get told off with:

> > Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<MyProduct>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`

I then updated the code, to remove the List to work with single objects, the same issue persists.

Why do I have to call the ListConvert.ChangeType when the T is already of that type?

Comment: Is your class generic? If so, it shouldn't be returning a concrete type. If it isn't, you should have List<T> anywhere. Which is it?

Comment: No, the class is not generic

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, sorry about deleting question, I hadn't worded it very well. It now (hopefully) makes more sense.

Comment: Not a problem, let me know if my answer is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here lies in understanding how C# generics work.

In C++, there was a concept of template specialization. That is, you could write:

```
void Foo<T> {}
void Foo<int> {}
```

If T was an int, it would use the specialized version, otherwise the generic. This is NOT allowed in C# generics. Either everything is generic, or everything isn't. When you write

```
public List<T> GetProductDetails<T>(string websiteHtmlCode, List<string> negativeWords)
```

You are now in the land of generics (albeit a generic method instead of class). Because you are now in the land of generics, making a call to a specific function:

```
List<MyProduct> GetProducts
```

Doesn't make any sense. What if T was `object`, or `String`? Returning a list of `MyProduct` would be very confusing, and almost assuredly fail when trying to cast (as your "working" code does). In other words, if you are always returning a `List<MyProduct>`, why bother with the generic (hence my earlier comment, they need to all be generic, or all concrete, you can't mix!).

The general rule of generics is "T is an `object`". That is all it is, and all it ever can be. If you need more specialization than just `object`, you need to add a `where` clause to your generic type argument. I kind of doubt you actually need that in this case, since you it looks like you are just doing a web request. You should be able to just change your function to:

```
List<T> GetProducts
```

At this point you may want to consider making the class generic as well, but that is up to you. If you can't make that change, I would remove the genericness from your method. You could do a switch on the type oF T but that isn't any better, and is very hard to understand/read.

MSDN for generic type constraints (`where`): [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx)

Please let me know if I can clarify anything!